# connecting to bitbucket and github from the same .gitconfig

Tags: linux, git, macos, github

I have a locally hosted version of bitbucket, and a github account. I want to be able to connect to both easily. I tried this `.gitconfig` version, does not work seamlessly. What Am I missing? What should I put under user in both systems?

```
#Github (default)
  Host gh
  HostName github.com
  User ?
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id.pub

#Bitbucket (secondary)
  Host bb
  HostName stash.company.com
  User ?
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id.pub
```

Comment: This does not look like a `.gitconfig`, but more like an [SSH config](https://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config).

Comment: I guess you are correct. Then how should the gitconfig looklike?

Comment: Would you give a little more detail on how you're going to "connect to both easily"? Normally this is achieved by having two remotes for a local repository and you can push to whichever you want. A "Git remote" is not necessarily tied to an SSH host.

Answer (score 0):

In your local repo, a "remote" is defined to tell git what repository to go to when doing things like push and pull.
The default name is "origin".
So we enter commands like "git pull origin main"

The command "git remote -v" will show the "remotes you have defined, like this:

git remote -v
origin  git@github.com:/.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:/.git (push)

You can define another remote to point to a different remote repo:
git remote add

So if you add a remote and call it bborigin then
git pull bborigin main
would pull the main branch on remote bborigin

(I do not know if you will need special steps to set up authentication on the different remotes)

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to put that in `~/.ssh/config`

That means you can:

- test your authentication with `ssh -Tv gh` or `ssh -Tv bb`
- use those Host entries in SSH URLs with

  - `git clone gh:me/myGitHubRepository`
  - `git clone bb:me/myBitBucketRepository`

Second, a typical global .gitconfig (in `$HOME\.gitconfig`) would look like:

```
[alias]
        st = status
        lg2 = log --graph --format=format:'%C(bold blue)%h%C(reset) - %C(bold cyan)%aD%C(reset) %C(bold green)(%ar)%C(reset)%C(bold yellow)%d%C(reset)%n''          %C(white)%s%C(reset) %C(bold white)- %an%C(reset)' --abbrev-commit
        lg = !"git lg2"
        br = branch
[user]
        name = You
        email = your@email.com
[core]
        autocrlf = false
        safecrlf = false
        commitGraph = true
        quotepath = false
        longpaths = true
[rebase]
        autostash = true
        autosquash = true
[pull]
        rebase = true
[protocol]
        version = 2
[gc]
        writeCommitGraph = true
[credential "helperselector"]
        selected = manager-core
[credential]
        helper = manager-core
        manager = manager-core
[init]
        defaultBranch = main
```

This assumes you have downloaded and installed [GCM (Git Credential Manager)](https://github.com/GitCredentialManager/git-credential-manager#download-and-install), the credential manager which helps caching your credentials (username/password) for HTTPS URL.
Not mandatory in your case, though, if you stick to SSH URLs.